# How to return a string from a node js api call

Tags: node.js

I have using a code snippet which will return a value  after post rest call to an api.

But where ever i am calling the function its not returning the value and  prints undefined.

when ever i will call any where getAccessToken(), its says undefiuned, but ifi print the value am getting the output.

How do the called will get the return value, do i need to change anything in the below code. 
Thanks

```js
var getAccessToken = exports.getAccessToken = function (res) { 
    // body...
 const request = require('request');
 const authKey='EAcEa4o4SkBLo9IpZpW4Y7oDn7d6b30GlouNh28pJ6Q='
 const ContentType='application/x-www-form-urlencoded' ;
 var postData={
   'grant_type':'client_credentials'
 };
 const options = {  
     url: 'https://xyz/v1/login',
     method: 'POST',
     headers: {
         'Content-Type': ContentType,
         'Authorization':authKey 
      },
     body:require('querystring').stringify(postData)
 };
 var token;
 request(options, function(errror, response, body) {  
  //console.log(JSON.parse(body));
       token= JSON.parse(body).access_token;
 });
 return token;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function doesn't return anything. You may use async/await, promises or callbacks to fix it.

```
exports.getAccessToken = async (res) => {
  ...
  return await request(...)
}
```

**OR**

```
exports.getAccessToken = function(res) {
  ...
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    ...
    request(options, function(errror, response, body) {
       var token = JSON.parse(body).access_token;
       resolve(token);
    }
  });
}

// Use it like
getAccessToken().then(function(token) { ... });
```

**OR**

```
exports.getAccessToken = function(res, cb) {
  ...
  request(options, function(errror, response, body) {
       var token = JSON.parse(body).access_token;
       cb(token);
    }
}

// Use it like
getAccessToken(res, function(token) { ... });
```

Comment: Thanks Rashd i used the callback as above but i see like my code is executing 2 times also the the output returns 2 times.

Comment: the code is executing 2 times am not surs is that the nature of callback, i have used like this             const express=require('express');
const authtoken=require('./AurhToken.js')
const app=express();
app.use((req,res,next)=>{
 authtoken.getAccessToken(res, function(fnToken) { 
  console.log("----token-----"+fnToken);
  });
 res.send("Success");
});

module.exports=app;

Comment: No, it should not be executed twice. I don't know how you designed your app with routes and middlewares, so maybe your middleware for getting access token is called twice somewhere, need debugging...

Comment: And if you do modern development, try not to use callbacks, use async/await instead